# Can not use VS after unistalling Net Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, multilingual

When I installed the Multilingual App Toolkit (Version 3.00.....), there was still an error (Picture 1). Thereupon I tryed to uninstall all Netframework Versions with the [Net Framework Cleanup Tool](http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog_Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip), but after restarting the computer. I can't install any Version of the Net Framework, because the Installer says that it's already installed. Although I have uninstalled it. The bigger Problem is that I can't use Visual Studio, because there are always more then 3 errors when I open or create a new Project (For Errors see Pictures below). I already use the Microsoft [.NET Framework Repair Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135) and reinstalled VS 2013, but the error is still there. I don't know what I should do?

Picture 1:

[image]

**Error when creating a new Project:**

```
Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'
```

**Error in the Properties Window(unfortunately German):**

```
Ausnahme beim Konstruieren des Inhalts dieses Frames. Diese Information wird auch in "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml" protokolliert.

Ausnahmedetails:
System.ArgumentException: Das Quellarray ist nicht lang genug. Überprüfen Sie srcIndex, die Länge und die Untergrenze des Arrays.
   bei System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.AddRefTab(Type tabType, Object component, PropertyTabScope type, Boolean setupToolbar)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.AddTab(Type tabType, PropertyTabScope scope)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.PropertyTabCollection.AddTabType(Type propertyTabType)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser.CreateUI()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowser..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowserService.get_PropertyBrowser()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.PropertyBrowser.PropertyBrowserService.get_Window()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIElementPane.CreateUIElementPane(Object& uiElement)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.UIElementDocumentObject.Init(Boolean initSize)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.InitializeDocumentObject(Object punkView)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.PropertyBrowserSwitcher.OnQuerySwitchPane(FrameMoniker frameMoniker)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.QuerySwitchPane(FrameMoniker frameMoniker)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.OnElementValueChanged(UInt32 elementid, Object varValueOld, Object varValueNew)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ContextSwitchFrame.OnToolWindowCreated()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.PropertyBrowserSwitcher.OnToolWindowCreated()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, UInt32 id)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

**Error when open a Project:**

[image]

**and an Error when debugging a Project or when terminating VS:**

```
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

**ActivityLog:**

[ActiveLog](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=9f79fe615ebcecea&id=9F79FE615EBCECEA!2104&authkey=!AFvMNKfcUXtsSSk)

I think it's hard to solve the Problem, but I hope someone can help me.

Christian

Comment: Just reinstall .net framework. Simlple. And in the future do not remove prerequisites.

Comment: @TomTom He states in his question that he cannot install any other versions of the framework. `I can't install any Version of the Net Framework, because the Installer says that it's already installed.`. His best bet is probably reinstalling Windows at this point!

Comment: Agree. Reinstall time then.

Comment: Thanks, I have refresh Windows and now I could install the MAL Toolkit. But now there is an new error: When I start Visual Studio there is only one screen http://1drv.ms/1hUAaTp. I have unistalled VS, but the Error is still there. I would be glad about an answer

Comment: Edit: When I reset VS befor starting it, all errors are still there.

Comment: I have now unistall Windows completely and now all works. Thanks for the help.